# Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGSize' and 'Int'

Tags: swift

I have a problem with the following code:

```
let torpedoNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Torpedo")

torpedoNode.position = player.position
torpedoNode.position.y += 5

torpedoNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: torpedoNode.size / 2)
```

The error that I get is the line:

```
torpedoNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: torpedoNode.size / 2)
```

The error is:

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGSize' and 'Int'

Comment: CGSize has a Width and a Height. Do you want to apply /2 on both?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I can now continue my project. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CGSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize) is a **struct** which contains two `CGFloat` values - width and height.

So you cannot divide it with an `Int`.

It seems that your [parameter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520261-init) requires a `CGFloat` anyway. So you should be dividing the height or width by 2 and passing instead.

```
torpedoNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: torpedoNode.size.width / 2) //or height whichever is appropriate
```

Comment: You do not need to create a `CGFloat` from the literal `2`. `torpedoNode.size.width / 2` works just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy yea i forgot type inference there for a second >.<